# Categorised Search in Drupal 7- Search Categorised by Content Type's Field

Tags: php, search, drupal-7, categories

I've one interesting requirement. Within my search results in Drupal 7, I want the search results to be shown in categories.

For e.g. If I search John Doe on Drupal 7 site, my search results page should show following results.

---

### Search Results for John Doe

**Arts Department**
3 results found.

There are 3 people named 'John Doe' stationed in Arts Department.

**Science Department**
7 results found.

There are 7 people named 'John Doe' stationed in Science Department.

**Medical Department**
19 results found.

There are 19 people named 'John Doe' stationed in Medical Department.

**All the other Pages**
101 results founf.

There are 101 'John Doe' keywords found in all the remaining pages of the site.

---

Now, what you see above is that I search `John Doe` on my website and it showed me the categorised search results on my site. The Department Categories ( Medical Department / Arts Department / Science Department) you see are the values entered for the field named "Department Name" on my Content Type.

I just want that whatever search term is written, it should be filtered out by the values of the `Department` field and should be shown in categories. All the other pages should be shown in `All the other Pages`.

Is it possible?

please help.

P.S. if you think there is some solution with which I can hard code department's names for the categories, that would be perfect too, as there would be only five departments.

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I would propose using **[Views](https://drupal.org/project/views)** module with **[Search_API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api)** module. Search API is the new powerful search tool for Drupal 7 which allows of heavy customization.

Of course the specific output can be done using a **Group by** Department Name field option in the views Display settings.